# How to put a JFrame icon

Tags: java, swing, resources, icons, jframe

I want to set an icon for my application in Java. I'm using Eclipse.

I don't know if the way of storing the icon (and the config file by the way) into the project is the best one (I accept suggestions to learn the best way).

Anyway I'm trying to use this line into my extended JFrame class:

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("img/icon.png"));
```

But doesn't work: still with the coffee cup icon.

How can I access to the icon into package estacionBase.img? Is there a better place to store it? How would I access it then?

[image]

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html read this on how to load resources from the classpath.

Comment: Very good question. I bet many are confused about that stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of saving your resources alongside your source files, save it outside `src` in a folder called something like `res`. It's a good idea to separate your source from your resources.

As for the icon, use `setIconImage(ImageIO.read("res/icon.png"));`

**However:**

If your icons are inside a `jar`, you'll have to use `ImageIO.read(Classname.class.getResource("res/icon.png"));`

I think that's right, however take care with your relative paths and if it's not working, the first thing to check would the your paths relative to where it's being executed from (whether that's from the .class dirs or from a jar at some stage).

Comment: Shall I place my "res" folder into the src folder, or outside? If I want the icons to stay inside the jar and not outside, isn't my proposal the way to follow?

Comment: Yeah sure, if you'd like to keep your icons inside the jar you are more than welcome to put the res folder inside your `src` folder which I think is what you have at the moment anyway. I'll edit my answer to accommodate that.

Comment: Though I would recommend outside. Usually you'd have folders like `src, bin, lib, res` which makes things like updating a lot easier. But it's completely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

For the saving issue: Create a new source folder in your project and call it *res* or so. Then you can put your ressources in there. As *res* is marked as a source folder, it will be in your jar as well.

For the loading, you can use

```
setIconImage(ImageIO.read("res/icon.png"));
```

or

```
setIconImage(
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/icon.png"), description).getImage()
);
```

Of course, it is also ok to have the images in between your source code. Most of the official Java demo's (for instance [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html)) do it that way. It's more compact. I wouldn't use that technique for larger projects though. It can get quite messy.

Comment: `.getImage()` is needed on `ImageIcon`. :-)

Comment: @MichałRus You are completely right. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your image into a second folder such as /res as other people suggested then use the code:

`setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("path/to/icon.png")));`

I tried this for my applications and it worked every time. Also, try not to put the image into a package as well.